# Can Font Awesome icons be used within cells of Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: icons, google-sheets, font-awesome

Is it possible to use Font Awesome icons with Google Spreadsheets or is it only Google Fonts available for Google Docs?

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Apps, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Actually, [a duplicate question exists](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62552/is-there-a-way-to-use-font-awesome-icons-in-google-docs) on WebApps. It's not possible to flag this as a dup because it's not on stackoverflow.com, but webapps.stackoverflow.com. Oh, well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spreadsheet or Docs? In Docs you can use but with add-on, for Spreadsheet only if you save the every icon you'd like as image, or use it in a side-bar/dialog/extende sheet in HTML, but not in the spreadsheet itself, as there's no way to use CSS in it, and doubt it will ever be.

Comment: I ment Spreadsheet sorry for confusing... Why do you think it will ever be? Google letting you use Google Fonts. Why not font-awesome?